# Angular: change child component data after parent component has been rendered

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a situation with two components: the parent component (AComponent) passes data consisting of an array with objects to its child component (BComponent) which displays this data into a table element. Until `rows` is defined, the table will show a loading indication. Below is a very basic recreation of my situation.

```
import data from '../../services/data.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  templateUrl: `
    <app-b [columns]="columns" [rows]="rows"></app-b>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.scss']
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

  columns: string[];
  rows: any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.columns = ['title', 'year', 'cast', 'genres'];
    this.fetchData().then((res: any[]) => this.rows = res);
  }

  fetchData = (): Promise<any[]> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(data);
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  templateUrl: `
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngIf="!rows">
        <td [colSpan]="columns.length">Loading...</td>
      </tr>
      <ng-container *ngIf="rows">
        <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
          <td>{{row.title}}</td>
          <td>{{row.year}}</td>
          <td>{{row.cast}}</td>
          <td>{{row.genres}}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </table>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./b.component.scss']
})
export class BComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() columns: string[];
  @Input() rows: any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
```

This approach works fine if the data is being fetched from an API, thus async. I tried to imitate an API call with delay via the `fetchData` function. The test data is derived from a local .json file which I got from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prust/wikipedia-movie-data/master/movies.json

But the problem I face is once I pass local data from AComponent to BComponent, which is not being fetch from an API and thus no more async operations. So we replace

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.columns = ['title', 'year', 'cast', 'genres'];
  this.fetchData().then((res: any[]) => this.rows = res);
}
```

with

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.columns = ['title', 'year', 'cast', 'genres'];
  this.rows = data;
}
```

It takes several seconds to render the view of BComponent due to the large amount of data which needs to be placed into the DOM and the entire view (AComponent + BComponent) is only shown once the rendering is done. So during this time the user is seeing a blank screen.

What I would like to achieve is that the columns and loading indication of BComponent are first rendered and shown, and afterwards the rows, replacing the loading indication once they are also fully rendered. So basicly the same as would happen when the data is asynchronous fetched from an API.

I've tried several things without success:

Splitting up BComponent into two separate components: one for the columns and one for the rows, which doesn't work because the parent component (AComponent) is only shown when all child components are fully rendered.

I also tried many things via Angular life cycle hooks. For example assigning the data to rows in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.rows = data;
}
```

But this drops the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error.

This is in essention what I want to achieve: assign and render the rows after the AComponent  view (and thus also its child views) has been initialised. But it seems like being initialized and actually being rendered are two different things within Angular. From what I've noticed, the rendering of views only starts once Angular has gone through all the life cycle hooks. A hook `AfterViewRendered` or something like that would be handy. So anything with hooks is not an option for my situation I think?

I've also tried wrapping the local data in an Observables or Promise to make it asynchronous:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.columns = ['title', 'year', 'cast', 'genres'];
  Promise.resolve().then(() => this.rows = data);
}
```

But that also doesn't work unless there is a delay in it with the help of `setTimeout`. The assigning of local data to rows needs to 'snap out' of the view initialisation and rendering fase in order to get the result I want which is the case with `setTimeout`. But I'm hoping there is a less dirty way of achieving this.

I'm out of ideas for this one... so any help or ideas for different approaches is very much appreciated.

Sorry if I got things wrong or misunderstandings.

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: I have pagination implemented on my table, but the table itself is a relative heavy component which explains the long rendering time I think. The overly large data.json file in this example is just to imitate the long rendering time of the table.

Answer (score 0):

**approach 1:**
Implement a paging mechanism, no need to show thousands of rows at once! we human can't process that amount of data all at once.

**approach 2:**  Implement virtual scrolling if you have to show all the data at once, the idea is to render only the visible rows and other rows are rendered on-demand once you scroll down.

I will detail in this answer how you do the second approach:

Make sure you have angular cdk installed, if not install it

```
npm i @angular/cdk
```

then add it to you app module

```
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
@NgModule({
 ...
 imports: [ ScrollingModule, ...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

next use it in your template like this

```html
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngIf="!rows">
        <td [colSpan]="columns.length">Loading...</td>
      </tr>
      <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport  *ngIf="rows" itemSize="50"> 
        <tr *cdkVirtualFor="let row of rows">
          <td>{{row.title}}</td>
          <td>{{row.year}}</td>
          <td>{{row.cast}}</td>
          <td>{{row.genres}}</td>
        </tr>
     </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
    </table>
```

You should have a better performance now using Virtual Scrolling

Comment: I have pagination implemented on my table, but the table itself is a relative heavy component which explains the long rendering time I think. The overly large data.json file in my example is just to imitate the long rendering time of the table.

Comment: what's your page size, in that case you shouldn't have renderring issues, the issues are due to IO overhead and json parsing while reading your local file. since you render per page  you should not have issues with rendreing IMHO!